# Open alert dialog in Bottom Navigation View while navigation to next fragment

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnavigationview

I am having an BottomNavigationView in my activity and i have five fragments and i have used Navigation Jetpack component.

Each and every time i move to next fragment by clicking the BottomNavigationView item, i have to ask for a confirmation dialog (If i have to navigate from this screen Yes/No). If Yes i can move to next screen else for No i have to dismiss the dialog and proceed.

I there any better in Navigation Jetpack component itself to handle this situation.

I not getting any clear picture for this

Answer (score 0):

When you select BottomNavigationView item, you can should use this code;
First step, define BottomNavigationView in onCreate.

```
    mBtmView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomView);
    mBtmView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Second step;

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    mMenuId = item.getItemId();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_food: {
//Show dialog to there. if reject swipe from your dialog, use setCurrentItem. 
        }
        break;
        case R.id.action_medical: {
//Show dialog to there. if reject swipe from your dialog, use setCurrentItem. 

        }
        break;
        case R.id.action_yoga: {
//Show dialog to there. if reject swipe from your dialog, use setCurrentItem. 

        }
        break;
        case R.id.action_postures: {
//Show dialog to there. if reject swipe from your dialog, use setCurrentItem. 

        }
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think this answer is corect

Comment: Check it, if it works, I would be glad if you approve of my answer.

Comment: This is an ordinary method used.

Comment: It works fine for ordinary method.

Since we are using navigation JetPack Component, the navigation.xml should be having an option to open dialog as `<fragment/>` which is available.

That too we are not using setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener,

Provided we use navController, AppBarConfiguration.

Is there any options available using Navigation JetPack component.

Comment: @Murat Çakır Even this code has some logical issues.

Comment: Yes, issues dosent matter. Those can be fixed. I need stuffs with Navigation Jetpack component.